# Attach existing attached image plane to newly created Camera. MEL

Tags: maya, mel

Does anyone know how to attach an exisiting image plane to another camera? Then be able to delete the camera the image plane was initially connected to. Everytime i try, it deletes the image plane from both cameras. I have even tried disconnecting the connection from the previous camera before deleting the first camera. No luck.. Any help would be great. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I want to create a clean and percise camera duplicate instead of using something like Duplicate special. This way I know exactly what is being connected to the new camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you duplicate camera, imageplane stay in the old camera shape. You need to detach from old camera and attach it to the new one:

```
imagePlane -e -detach imagePlane1;
imagePlane -e -camera camera2;
```

Comment: When you delete the old camera, it deletes the image plane with it. That was my whole initial problem. Are you not getting the same issue?